# JQuery .load() error Object Required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some issues here to load a content into my div every 5 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function () 
{
$('div#tprincipal').load('getdataprincipal.php'); // Line 37
}, 5000);
</script>
```

And here is my Div:

```
<div id="tprincipal" class="tprincipal"></div>
```

It workds greate, but keep giving me an error on IE8  ( Object required Line 37 ).

the page getdataprincipal.php has only a simple Mysql request and an echo to show some informations that I have to check every 5 seconds.

The thing is that I have loads of people at work using the page with that error coming every 5 seconds and at end of the day IE8 stop responding and they have to close all windows and start again.

ps* IE8 is the company who doesn't change it and I can't force them. The only browser over there for 400 folks work with it.

But I have the same issue at home with IE11.

here is my PHP page

```
<?php include("connect.php");

$query_ajax = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM AGENT WHERE STATUS != '' AND STATUS!='LOGOUT' AND STATUS!='KICKED' AND STATUS!='' AND LEVEL_STATUS!=''");

while ($array_ajax = mysql_fetch_array($query_ajax)){

if($array_ajax["STATUS"]=="Disponible") echo $array_ajax['NOM']." : <b><font color='green'>".$array_ajax["STATUS"]."</font></b></div><br />";
if($array_ajax["STATUS"]=="Call") echo $array_ajax['NOM']." : <b><font color='red'>".$array_ajax["STATUS"]."</font></b></div><br />";
if($array_ajax["STATUS"]=="Ne pas deranger") echo $array_ajax['NOM']." : <b><font color='red'>".$array_ajax["STATUS"]."</font></b></div><br />";
if($array_ajax["STATUS"]=="Mode RUN") echo $array_ajax['NOM']." : <b><font color='orange'>".$array_ajax["STATUS"]."</font></b></div><br />";
};
?>
```

Comment: please provide your php

Comment: Is the `id` unique on the page?  I seem to remember that IE handles non-unique `id`s differently than other browsers in that it returns nothing at all when requesting the element with that `id`.  I think.

Comment: I would be willing to wager @David is probably correct. Can you confirm that `$('div#tprincipal')` is even returning anything? I have a hunch that this call returns null or something of the like which is why it is blowing up.

Comment: @David nailed it...  I've seen this before with invalid html as well (ie, a rogue close tag `</X>`in the middle of it somewhere as well.

Comment: the ID is unique yes .... I checked it before.

Comment: @EltondeSouza: Since the error is client-side, showing the server-side code isn't *entirely* helpful.

Comment: someone asked me to post my PHP code so i did it. I really don't get it. in Chrome i have the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of null

Comment: here the webpage working ... but not in all browsers... Chrome give me the errors  .... http://avocis-lausanne.ch/TS/plan.php

Comment: Have you tried fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler? it's a proxy that would work over IE8 and tell you more informations on what is going on...

Comment: @SimonPaquet no I didn't. Can't download at work. will try it at home. I googled every where still can't find the solution.
Does someone know something that would replace load() of jQuery and not Kill the browser at the end of the day ? :)

Comment: Your problem might be asyncronous....

You do another call to the server when the first call did not come back positive.

You could try to replace .load() function with .ajax() and wait the server response before reseting the interval.

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: "getdataadmin.php",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
    $("#tadmin").html(data);
  }
});

}, 3000);   .............. I am having exactly the same issue, same error. :(

Comment: No, Actually ajax Worked !! Thank you very Much !!!